# How to display a blank div element?

Tags: css

I have a blank div class that is called spacer ... it has a blue background and a width of 100% of the container (the body) ...

What I have found is that the spacer will not DISPLAY unless I toss some character in it. I can color the character blue so it is hidden, but that is so inelegant.

What is the CORRECT way to do this.

Answer (score 16):

Give it a height.

Otherwise, with no content, it has zero height and is effectively invisible.

Answer (score 11):

Add `&nbsp;` inside to have some content inside the `div`

Answer (score 3):

add `height` to the div

```
<div style="height:10px; width:100%"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the `<p>` tags with `<br />` tags using regex. This was enough for our use case of sending user-generated emails that sometimes had empty line breaks in them.

```
var newhtml = Regex.Replace(html, "<p[^>]*></p>", "<br />", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```